# How to train TensorFlow's deeplab model on Cityscapes?

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to train the current deeplab model in TensorFlow to reasonable accuracy using 4 GPUs with 11GB? I seem to be able to fit 2 batches per GPU, so am running a total batch size of 8 across 4 clones.

Following the [instructions included with the model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/cityscapes.md), I get a mean IoU of < 30% after 90,000 iterations.

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim python deeplab/train.py \
--logtostderr --training_number_of_steps=90000 \
--train_split="train" --model_variant="xception_65" \
--atrous_rates=6 --atrous_rates=12 --atrous_rates=18 \
--output_stride=16 --decoder_output_stride=4 --train_crop_size=769 \
--train_crop_size=769 --train_batch_size=8 --num_clones=4 \
--dataset="cityscapes" \
--tf_initial_checkpoint=deeplab/models/xception/model.ckpt \
--train_logdir=$LOGDIR \
--dataset_dir=deeplab/datasets/cityscapes/tfrecord
```

I have tried with batch norm both enabled and disabled without much difference in outcome.

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to reproduce results using your settings?

Comment: Using a much higher learning rate (1e-2) I was able to get results that are closer to the published results (I don't have enough machines for the large batch size used in the paper).

Comment: Cool thanks, can you please specify other parameters for training as well? I also dont have much resources.

Comment: I think I used a batch size of 15 and crop size of 513, the rest default.

Comment: @MagnusW Do you know what setting the crop size to 513 (or 769) actually does? It doesn't just take random crops of 513x513 (or 769x769), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I needed a much larger step length than the default. 1e-2 gives results  closer to the published results, with batch size 15 and a smaller crop window size.

Comment: Do you mind telling what your final params configuration and accuracy were? I'm trying to reproduce the mobilenet version. Training from scratch gets me not close to their published results.

Answer (score 0):

if you check this link https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md
It has links to pretrained models for MobileNet v2 and DeepLab trained on Cityscapes. You can modify the existing shell scripts present here to train on cityscapes.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to train on a different dataset and want to reproduce their training on Cityscapes to ensure I have a good baseline, so pre-trained models aren't useful to me. I followed their instructions but don't have enough GPUs to run the suggested batch size of 16. I was not expecting performance to be quite this poor using a batch size of 8 however.

Comment: @MagnusW, Did you actually find a way to train deepLab from scratch, I mean without even using any pre-existing checkpoint?

Comment: @Anubhav, Yes - I was able to train from the deeplab/models/xception/model.ckpt checkpoint. Haven't tried training a random-initialized network.

Comment: @MagnusW, I didn't find any such pre-trained checkpoint in the standard repo. Are you using `models/research/deeplab/core/xception.py` to generate this checkpoint? and later, use this ckpt as a starting point to train deeplab on cityScapes dataset? How much time does it take to get the decent results on annotating the images? Also, I tried the pre-trained `deeplabv3_cityscapes_train_2018_02_06.` model on CityScapes dataset and the valuation results in just full pink color on all the images? Do you know what's happening? any suggestion would be helpful.!

Comment: I used the [pre-trained checkpoints here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md), and trained on Cityscapes with learning rate 1e-2 using that as the starting point.

Comment: @MagnusW, I got it! thanks, so you started with the `xception_**_imagenet` checkpoints that are pretrained on ImageNet!. Did you tried `resnet_v1_**_beta_imagenet`? & did you get some improvement in accuracy?