# How to train a Deeplab model from scratch in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using [deepLab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) to generate semantic segmentation masked images for a video in cityscapes datasets. So, I started with the pre-trained model [xception65_cityscapes_trainfine](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md) provided on the modelzoo and trained it further on the dataset.

I am curious to know How I can start training it from scratch? and not end up just using the pre-trained model? could anyone suggest a direction on How I can achieve it?

Any contribution from the community will be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49356743/how-to-train-tensorflows-deeplab-model-on-cityscapes/49731340?noredirect=1#comment92536186_49731340) post.

Comment: What is the specific programming question here?

Comment: how to train deepLab from scratch(not using pre-trained weights) in tensorFlow on the cityscapes dataset?